# Batch file, writing to text files gives error in wordpad

Tags: batch-file

This is my first time writing a simple batch file. I want to write some lines to two text files. The writing to the files goes very well, except that wordpad is started twice and gives an error that it cannot find C:\WINDOWS\system32\to and I cannot figure out why this is...

```
@echo off
set /p UserInputProject=What is the name of the project you want to create? 

;;;;;;;;;;;;;; write to host file first ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
echo 127.0.0.1 %UserInputProject%.local >> %hostspath%
echo 127.0.0.1 %UserInputProject%.cms.local >> %hostspath%

;;;;;;;;;;;;;; write to vhost file second ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
set vhostpath=C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
echo ^<VirtualHost ^*:80^> >> %vhostpath%
echo    ServerAdmin webmaster@local >> %vhostpath%
echo    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/%UserInputProject%/httpdocs" >> %vhostpath%
echo    ServerName %UserInputProject%.local >> %vhostpath%
echo ^</VirtualHost^> >> %vhostpath%
```

Comment: `;;;;;;;;;;;;;; write to vhost file second ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;` is not a comment.Change `;` to `:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;` is a standard delimiter in batch as well as `,=<space><tab>` and generally is treated as a space - so the lines `;;;;;;;;;;;;;; write to vhost file second ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;` are not commented.

`write.exe` is exactly the wordpad and because the `.exe`is part of `%cmdext%` variable it is started.The first argument is `to` so wordpad tries to open the file `to` file.
Try to put `rem` or to change `;` to `:` in the lines you want to comment.